# How to get cloud firestore document unique Id before adding data to cloud firestore as Realtime database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

We can get pushed Key in realtime database before adding data but in cloud firestore I could not find any method to find unique key before adding data.

```
String uniqueKey = ref.push().getKey();
```

So  I am doing two operation add  and then update .If I can get unique key before adding data to firestore I can do it one operation just add with unique key included in the document.

Currently I am doing like this.

Collection Reference

```
final sitesRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('book_mark')
      .doc(getUserId())
      .collection("link")
      .withConverter<SiteModel>(
        fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => SiteModel.fromJson(snapshots.data()!),
        toFirestore: (siteModel, _) => siteModel.toJson(),
      );
```

Add document then get document Id from response then update the document with document Id.**So if update operation is failed somehow I could not access the document anymore. So it will create a problem down the line**.

```
Future<String> addSiteFireStore(SiteModel siteModel) async {
    try {
      DocumentReference<SiteModel> response = await sitesRef.add(siteModel);
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
      data['docId'] = response.id;
      sitesRef.doc(response.id).update(data);
      _logger.fine("Link added successfully");
      return "Link added successfully";
    } on Exception catch (_) {
      _logger.shout("Could not add link.Please try again");
      return "Could not add link.Please try again";
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to get the document Id beforehand?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a new document reference without writing to it by calling `doc()` (without arguments) on a `CollectionReference`. Then you can get the `id` property from the new document reference, similar to how you call `getKey()` on the new RTDB reference.

So:

```
final newRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('book_mark')
      .doc();
final newId = newRef.id;
```

Also see the FlutterFire documentation on [`CollectionReference.doc()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html).